# yield vs. return - DFS binary tree problem

Tags: python, algorithm, binary-tree, yield-return

Anyone please explain why 'return' isn't working here if I wrote `if not node.left and not node.right: return node.val`
but working if the code goes:

```
class Solution:
def leafSimilar(self, root1: Optional[TreeNode], root2: Optional[TreeNode]) -> bool:
    def dfs(node):
        if not node:
            return None
        if not node.left and not node.right:
            yield node.val
        for i in dfs(node.left):
            yield i
        for i in dfs(node.right):
            yield i
    return all(a == b for a, b in itertools.zip_longest(dfs(root1), dfs(root2)))
```

with the example input root1 = [1,2,3], root2 = [1,3,2]

Why the result falsely shows 'True' in the 'return' case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The function you've shown is a generator function, because it contains several `yield` statements. Even if you don't run any of those statements for certain inputs, their existence makes the whole function a generator function regardless.

When you call a generator function, the value you get back isn't its return value. Rather, it will be a generator object (a kind of iterator). You only get the return value when you consume the generator object with a `yield from` expression:

```
gen = some_generator_function()  # this assigns the generator object to gen
result = yield from gen          # this assigns the return value (after yielding values)
```

In the code you show, the calls to the generator function are being iterated on directly by `for` loops or indirectly by the `itertools.izip_longest` function. Nether of those approaches let you get a hold of the value `return`ed by the generator function (though you probably *could* rewrite the loops to use `yield from`). Generally speaking, generator functions *often* don't return anything at all (which is equivalent to the `return None` that you're doing in the base case). It doesn't make much sense to `return node.val` in the current code. If you want to skip the loops (which will be over empty generators, which should be quick, but it's still doing a little useless work), you could `yield node.val` and then `return` on the next line (still within the `if` block).

Answer (score 0):

In Python, the `return` statement is used to return a value from a function, and it immediately exits the function.

When you use `return node.val`, you are trying to return a value from the middle of a generator function. Generators use the `yield` statement to produce values one at a time and retain the state of the function between calls. Using `return` in this context doesn't make sense because it would exit the generator function immediately, preventing the subsequent values from being yielded.